# Expanding Binomial with Absolute Value

Tags: absolute-value, binomial-theorem

I want to expand the least-squares formula $\sum |a-b|^2$, but I can't follow the reasoning behind *what I've heard is* the answer:

$|a-b|^2 = |a|^2 - 2|ab| + |b|^2$

Instructions or a link would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT!:
Corrected the formula >.<

Comment: The formula you give is wrong. The exact form depends on what $a$ and $b$ are. Real or complex numbers or vectors?

Comment: I think I am assuming they are real. Thanks @JoonasIlmavirta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x$ is a real number, then $|x|^2=x^2$.
(If you are unsure about this, check separately the cases when $x$ is positive and negative.)
Thus
$$
|a-b|^2
=
(a-b)^2
=
a^2-2ab+b^2
=
|a|^2-2ab+|b|^2.
$$
The formula is wrong if you put absolute values on $ab$.
In fact, $|a-b|^2=|a|^2-2|ab|+|b|^2$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ have the same sign.

---

The complex case:
Write $a=re^{i\phi}$ and $b=se^{i\theta}$.
Then
$$
|a-b|^2
=
(a-b)(\bar a-\bar b)
=
(re^{i\phi}-se^{i\theta})(re^{-i\phi}-se^{-i\theta})
=
r^2+s^2-(e^{i(\phi-\theta)}+e^{-i(\phi-\theta)})sr
=
|a|^2+|b|^2-2\text{Re}(a\bar b).
$$
This can also be written as $|a|^2+|b|^2-2\cos(\phi-\theta)|a||b|$ if you prefer such form.
I omitted some details in the calculations; ask if you can't fill the gaps.

---

If you need further clarification, do ask.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I'm working with it now. I think I would need to do the complex case as well.

Comment: @NolanHergert, I added the complex case to my answer.

Comment: What about $\mid a+b\mid^2$?

Comment: @Zzz, you can use the same formulas, just changing the sign in front of the 2. To see this, combine the formulas I gave with $a+b=a-(-b)$.